# Query to fetch just one item from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server, plsql, plsqldeveloper

hr_org with the following columns :-

```
Org id  Spoc  Name
123     HR    A
123     IT    A
123     VP    A
67      IT    B
78      HR    C
78      IT    C
```

i want to create a query in which only those names come in which only IT Spoc is defined.

For eg :-

```
select name 
from hr_org
where SPOC ='IT'
```

will give A And B 
but for A other spoc(HR AND VP) have been defied as well. My output should just fetch B.

Comment: Why does it fetch `B`?  What are your rules that define `B` as the correct one of the 3 to fetch?

Answer (score 1):

```
select name 
from hr_org
where SPOC ='IT' and name not in (select name from hr_org where SPOC<>'IT')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from hr_org h1
where spoc='IT'
and not exists (
    select 1
    from hr_org h2
    where h2.spoc <> h1.spoc
    and h2.name = h1.name
)
```